# PostCssNotFoundError on GitHub pages using Jekyll

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, postcss

I made a Jekyll site using postcss. It runs perfectly fine on the local server, but when I try to deploy it using GitHub pages I get an error:

```
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::PostCss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.css': PostCssNotFoundError
```

Locally PostCSS Server listening on port 8124...